# Frequent SOAP calls with Camel

Tags: java, apache-camel

I am working on a project where I have to invoke a SOAP service every 30 seconds and retrieve some information. As of now I have been using Camel "timer" component to poll and then invoking a bean where I am performing my SOAP call. I was wondering if there is a better way possible within Apache Camel to make frequent SOAP calls.

thanks for your input.

Comment: Any particular problems you are worried about using a timer? I'd just use the Quartz timer. Obviously I'd think about ways of turning it on and off, eg for integration test or certain times of day, and triggering it manually.

Answer (score 1):

Using [Camel-Quartz](http://camel.apache.org/quartz.html) could give you more control.